# Ubuntu - New Ubuntu server won't accept new public IP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ip, internet

I'm currently setting up the servers and since I gave server HachiSoftware02 it's public IP it won't let me connect to it via SSH.

When it had a local IP it worked fine and I need the server for application builds.

`netstat -tulpn`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEbWA.jpg

`ifconfig`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQvAE.jpg

Comment: Doest  it ping ?
Is there a firewall ? 
Is your IP being routed ? 
What are your server logs indicating ? 

<== Basic troubleshooting

Comment: You need to provide more details.

Comment: result for `netstat -tulpn`, `iptables -L -v- n` and `ifconfig` please :)

Comment: How did you configure the new IP? eth0 has no valid IPv4 address attached to it? Distro?

Answer (score 1):

You havent configured any public IP on your eth0 do so by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`

In this format :

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address A.B.C.D 
        netmask A.B.C.D 
        network A.B.C.D 
        broadcast A.B.C.D 
        gateway A.B.C.D
```

And then run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`